# Multiple route mapping to different matplotlib graphs in flask app

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I have this "flask app" with two links, each mapping to different matplotlib visualizations, for example: localhost:5000/line_chart and localhost:5000/bar_chart.

When I start the server, and click the a route (any of them), I see what I expect.

localhost:5000/bar_chart

[image]

When I go back and view the other link, both graphs break.

localhost:5000/line_chart

[image]

localhost:5000/bar_chart

[image]

I can reproduce this every time by closing the server then running the "run.py" script again. Seems to be an overwriting conflict with the in-memory buffer. Has anyone had this issue before?

app/views.py

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # this allows PNG plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64

from flask import render_template
from app import app
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
res = ''
navigation = [['Line Chart','line_chart'],['Bar Chart','bar_chart']]
res = res + '<h1>Matplotlib Chart Examples</h1>'
res = res + '<ul>'

for item in navigation:
    name = item[0]
    link = item[1]
    res = res + '<li><a href="' + link + '">'+ name +'</a></li>'

res = res +'</ul>'
return res


@app.route('/bar_chart')
    def bar_chart():

    movies = ["Annie Hall", "Ben-Hur", "Casablanca", "Gandhi", "West Side Story"]
    num_oscars = [5, 11, 3, 8, 10]

    # bars are by default width 0.8, so we'll add 0.1 to the left coordinates
    # so that each bar is centered

    xs = [i + 0.1 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)]

    # plot bars with left x-coordinates [xs], heights [num_oscars]
    plt.bar(xs, num_oscars)
    plt.ylabel("# of Academy Awards")
    plt.title("My Favorite Movies")

    # label x-axis with movie names at bar centers
    plt.xticks([i + 0.5 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)], movies)

    return compute(plt)


@app.route('/line_chart')
def line_chart():

    years = [1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
    gdp = [300.2, 543.3, 1075.9, 2862.5, 5979.6, 10289.7, 14958.3]

    # create a line chart, years on x-axis, gdp on y-axis
    plt.plot(years, gdp, color='green', marker='o', linestyle='solid')

    # add a title
    plt.title("Nominal GDP")

    # add a label to the y-axis
    plt.ylabel("Billions of $")

    return compute(plt)


def compute(plt):
    # run plt.plot, plt.title, etc.
    figfile = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')
    figfile.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning of file

    #figfile.getvalue()  extracts string (stream of bytes)
    figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())

    return render_template('index.html',
                       title='matplotlib chart',
                       results=figdata_png)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need two figures, test this code and tell what happened:

```
@app.route('/bar_chart')
    def bar_chart():

    movies = ["Annie Hall", "Ben-Hur", "Casablanca", "Gandhi", "West Side Story"]
    num_oscars = [5, 11, 3, 8, 10]

    # bars are by default width 0.8, so we'll add 0.1 to the left coordinates
    # so that each bar is centered

    xs = [i + 0.1 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)]

    # plot bars with left x-coordinates [xs], heights [num_oscars]
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.bar(xs, num_oscars)
    plt.ylabel("# of Academy Awards")
    plt.title("My Favorite Movies")

    # label x-axis with movie names at bar centers
    plt.xticks([i + 0.5 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)], movies)

    return compute(plt, 1)


@app.route('/line_chart')
def line_chart():

    years = [1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
    gdp = [300.2, 543.3, 1075.9, 2862.5, 5979.6, 10289.7, 14958.3]

    # create a line chart, years on x-axis, gdp on y-axis
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(years, gdp, color='green', marker='o', linestyle='solid')

    # add a title
    plt.title("Nominal GDP")

    # add a label to the y-axis
    plt.ylabel("Billions of $")

    return compute(plt,2)

def compute(plt, fignum):
    # run plt.plot, plt.title, etc.
    plt.figure(fignum)
    figfile = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')
    figfile.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning of file

    #figfile.getvalue()  extracts string (stream of bytes)
    figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())

    return render_template('index.html',
                       title='matplotlib chart',
                       results=figdata_png)
```

Comment: that worked. wow.. thank you so much. this has been bothering me for the passed two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that solution didn't work. It seems that there is a race condition when trying to access plot. I first tried to use a lock from a library, but that didn't work, so instead I sort of engineered out a lock. In my case, I wanted to create `n` images using the same function on the same view, so I started by creating a list in the following way:

```
queue = [False for i in range(n)]
```

Then, my flask app look something like this:

```
@app.route('/vis/<j>')
def vis(j):
    global queue
    # We check that it's image's #j turn, as if it was single threaded
    j = int(j)
    if j == 0:
        for i in range(len(queue)):
            queue[i] = False
    else:
        while not queue[j-1]:
            # If it's not, we sleep for a short time (from time import sleep)
            sleep(0.5)
    # This is not important, it's how I was plotting some random figures
    # (from random import seed) (from datetime import datetime)
    seed(datetime.now())
    n = 10
    p1 = [randint(0, 10) for _ in range(n)]
    p2 = [randint(0, 10) for _ in range(n)]
    t = [i for i in range(n)]
    fig = plt.figure(j)
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(t, p1, color='blue')
    plt.plot(t, p2, color='orange')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Value')
    # Save the plot
    img = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img, dpi=128)
    img.seek(0)
    # We finished using everything related to plot, so we free the "lock"
    queue[j] = True
    # Return the object as a file that can be accessed
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

Finally, when wanting to display this in my flask app, all I had to do was using this `<img src="/vis/1">` in my html file.

---

Edit: I forgot one of the most important part! For some reason, this would still create some unrelated thread issue. I looked it up and that's when I came with the full solution. The threading issue was solved by adding at the beginning of the file:

```
 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

For some reason, using that `Agg` backend solved the second threading I was having. I don't really have a good explanation for that, but it does work, so it's enough for me.

---

Alternatively, what also worked was running the app disabling threads by adding:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(threading=False, debug=True)
```

I don't know however, at the moment, whether this works in production, so I preferred the other solution. :)

I hope this helps if you had the same issue!

Comment: By the way, this is of course extendable to any case in which you plot two or more different images. In such case, you don't have the first condition but directly the corresponding for or while statement depending on whether it is the first image or any of the others respectively.